# Where is the FILE struct allocated?

Tags: c, file-io

In C, when opening a file with

```
FILE *fin; 
fin=fopen("file.bin","rb");
```

I only have a pointer to a structure of FILE. Where is the actual FILE struct allocated on Windows machine? And does it contain all the necessary information for accessing the file?

My aim is to dump the whole data segment to disk and then to reload the dumped file back to the beginning of the data segment. The code that reloads the dumped file is placed in a separate function. This way, the `fin` pointer is local and is on the stack, thus is not being overwritten on reload. But the `FILE` struct itself is not local. I take care not to overwrite the memory region of size `sizeof(FILE)` that starts at the address `fin`.

The

```
fread(DataSegStart,1,szTillFin,fin);
fread(dummy,1,sizeof(FILE),fin);
fread(DataSegAfterFin,1,szFinTillEnd,fin);
```

operations completes successfully, but I get an assertion failure on

```
fclose(fin)
```

Do I overwrite some other necessary file data other than in the FILE struct?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by storing the contents of a FILE structure about an open file? I would never think the FILE struct was meant to be *stored*.

Comment: Actually, I don't need to store the FILE structure particularly. I just dump the whole data segment.

Comment: @NickBedford: You miss the point of the question.  The intent is to reload the entirety of the heap from a file -- but this would overwrite the ``FILE`` structure, and that would obviously break things, so the question is how to avoid stomping on that while loading everything else.

Comment: Got it. That sounds like a messy idea to me, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual instance of the `FILE` structure exists within the standard library. Typically the standard library allocates some number of FILE structures, which may or may not be a fixed number of them. When you call `fopen()`, it returns a pointer to one of those structures.

The data within the `FILE` structure likely contains pointers to other things such as buffers. You're unlikely to be able to save and restore those structures to disk without some really deep integration with your standard library implementation.

You may be interested in something like [CryoPID](http://cryopid.berlios.de/) which does process save and restore at a different level.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification on the linked buffers issue. Could somebody point me to the details of the implementation on Windows, VS2008?

Comment: Visual Studio comes with the source code for the standard libraries. I've never seen this documented outside of the source code itself.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're trying to do something dangerous, unlikely to work.

`fopen` allocates a `FILE` structure and initializes it. `fclose` releases it. How it allocates it and what it puts in it is implementation dependent. It could contain a pointer to another piece of memory, which is also allocated somewhere (since it's buffered I/O, I guess it does allocate a buffer somewhere).

Writing code that relies on the internals of `fopen` is dangerous, most likely won't work, and surely won't be stable and portable.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not trying to write a portable code here. And I noted that it is being implemented on Windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have a pointer to a `FILE` object, so technically you know where it is but you should be aware that `FILE` is deliberately an opaque type. You shouldn't need to know what it contains, you just need to know that you can pass it to functions that know about it to perform certain actions. Additionally, `FILE` may not be a complete type so `sizeof(FILE)` might not be correct and, additionally, the object might contain pointers to other structures. Simply avoiding overwriting the `FILE` object is not likely to be sufficient for you to avoid corrupting the program by writing over most of its memory.

Comment: So what do you suggest in advice? Instead of avoid reloading 'sizeof(FILE)' bytes, to reload to the dummy buffer 'sizeof(fin)' bytes?

Comment: @ZKim: I don't know what problem you are actually trying to solve but I don't think that you are going to be successful writing over the data segment of the currently running process. I would have thought that you are almost certain to corrupt _something_.

Answer (score 0):

FILE is defined in stdio.h. It contains all the information about the file but, looking at the code you show, I think you don't understand its purpose. It is created and run through the operating system with the C library which fills FILE with information about the file but it is not contained in the file itself.

Comment: I mean where does the FILE struct allocated, not defined. I mean, I get only the pointer to it. How is it being _declared_, like malloc'ed or what?

Comment: When you do an fopen, a FILE struct is created and returned. I'm sure the space is created using malloc or similar.